# Bidirectional communication between keyboard and android device (AOA)

Tags: android, usb, hid, accessory

I want to create an android application where I can communicate with a keyboard (hid). Firstly, I try to communicate with the keyboard via **usb** host but it seems keyboard doesn't appear on UsbManager.getDeviceList().

I have read about the AOA. My problem is that I don't understand how can I set up the protocol. I have understood android device should communicate with an accessory but I don't understand if a standard keyboard is an accessory or if have modify my keyboard. In the second case, how I can do this ? I want plug my keyboard **usb** directly on the android device.

I have tried example of application using accessory but mUsbManager.getAccessoryList() return null. How can I know the model and manufacturer to set on **usb** accessory filter ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I have worked on External keyboard integration with android device. I also noticed all keyboard will not recognize by device, only lenevo and Logitech keyboard can detectable. If you are looking for code then see this [Link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29072810/set-disable-focus-on-a-certain-item-in-gridview?noredirect=1#comment46381131_29072810)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but on my case, I can't use keyevent interface. I need to get key down on service (not on an activity) and I also have to communicate from android device to keyboard.

Comment: That means you want to communicate between service and keyboard.

Comment: Yes, that's right. but it's not possible to get key on service (only with an activity)